# A problem with Cauchy Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I want to resolve the folowing contour integral, using the Cauchy theorem:

$$
\oint_C \cot(\pi z)\,dz
$$
where $C$ is rectangle defined by 
$x=\frac{1}{2},x=\pi, y=-1, y=1 $

I do understand that $\cot$ is a function that is indeterminate at $z=0,1,2,\ldots$ , but... What should I do then? I'm lost.

Thank you so much for any help in the problem.

Comment: You can refer to residue theorem since there are several isolated singularities in the region.

Comment: The function being integrated has simple poles at $1$, $2$, and $3$, and those are the only ones inside the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{3}\lim_{z \to n}\bracks{\pars{z - n}\cot\pars{\pi z}}
&=\sum_{n = 1}^{3}{\cos\pars{\pi n} \over \pi\cos\pars{\pi n}}
=\color{#44f}{\large{3 \over \pi}}
\end{align}